# gLTF 2.0 models not showing in A-Frame

Tags: node.js, blender, aframe, gltf

From the Kronos Github, I downloaded the [A-Frame Exporter](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter) add-on and added it to Blender.

I then exported a simple starting cube from Blender and named it "test.gltf" (i have also tried "test.gbl") and placed it inside of my A-Frame scene.

I am using A-Frame Master (not 0.70)

Here's the code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Aetheria</title>
<meta name="description" content="Aetheria" />
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.6.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
```

```
  <!-- Primitives. -->
  <a-box position="-1 0.6 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
  <a-sphere position="0 1.35 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
  <a-cylinder position="1 0.85 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D"></a-cylinder>
  <a-plane position="0 0.1 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
  <a-gltf-model src="model/invertedsphere/test.gltf"></a-gltf-model>

  <!-- Background sky. -->
  <a-sky height="2048" radius="30" src="#skyTexture" theta-length="90" width="2048"></a-sky>

  <!-- Ground. -->



</a-scene>
```

The cube (test.gltf) does not appear in the scene. I have tried scaling it up, scaling it down, every troubleshooting step that  I can imagine. There are no errors from the node console (I am running node liveserver in Ubuntu 14.04) and it gives me this output when I reload the page:

```
[8528] 1ms           0B GET    304 /aetheria/model/invertedsphere/test.gltf
```

I am able to view the model in Microsoft's 3D Builder and indeed see a plain, grey starting cube.

How do I make my glTF models visible?

[zip file containing test.bin and test.gltf](http://mold.bz/invertedsphere.zip)

Comment: beside the .gltf there are also other files exported. (a .bin, textures ). Do you place them with the .gltf on your server ?

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski Yes. In this case, there is no texture, but there is a testing.gltf and a testing.bin on the server.

Comment: is it a glitch server, or your own ?

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski My own server, I am using npm on ubuntu 14.04 with livereload.

Comment: i was asking, because glitch doesn't find those assets, but i'm not sure what could be the problem in your case :(

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski I uploaded test.bin and test.gltf above

Comment: its working at my random hosting: http://vrrocks.pl/experiments/1/2.html

Comment: which means the .gltf is fine, are you sure the paths are correct ?

Comment: wait, are you using the a-frame master, or a-frame 0.6.0 ?

Comment: Yeah, i think the A-Frame version is the issue here. 0.6.0 supported only the previous glTF version, which there is much less tooling for. I'd upgrade to 0.7.0 or master branch if you can. Also good idea to test on https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/, that can give some diagnosis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i remember a-frame 0.6.0 used glTF 1.0 in the gltf-model component.
If You are reffering to the master build, make sure you're using

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.7.1/aframe.min.js"></script>
```

Which is the master branch as of this day.

---

Otherwise, use the glTF 1.0 exporter.

Comment: It looks like I had 0.7.1 installed, but ```angle initscene``` is creating project scenes for A-Frame 0.6.0, thus the issue. I'll be creating scenes by hand from now on. Thanks for your help!